# Cache hits, misses and prediction - impact on performance

Tags: c, caching, cpu, microbenchmark

I coded the following toy benchmark.

```
int N = 1024*4096;
unsigned char *ary = malloc(N);
ary[0] = 1;
int stride, i;
double start, end;
int sum;
for(stride = 1; stride < N; ++stride) {
    start = getCPUTime();

    sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i+=stride) {
        sum += ary[i];
    }

    end = getCPUTime();
    printf("stride %d time %f sum %d\n", stride, (end - start)/(N/stride), sum);
}
```

Basically, it iterates through an array in different strides. I then plotted the results:

[image]

*(Results are smoothed)*

When stride is ~128, the CPU can fit all of the data to be accessed in L1 Cache. Given the linearity of accesses future reads are presumably predicted.

My question is, why does the average time for read keep rising after that? My reasoning for stride=~128 also holds for values greater than that.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered the great impact on caching of your print statement?

Comment: Can the constant increase of average time be bound to soft-page-faults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that the code you used? All it does is read data from 16 MB. I ran it on my PC, where 16 MB is from RAM, calculating MB/second, which was 993 at stride 2, reducing to 880 at stride 999. Based on measuring microseconds running time, your time calculation produced 0.0040 at stride 2, increasing 0.0045 at stride 999.

There are all sorts of reasons for speed reductions at increased strides like, burst reading, cache alignment and different memory banks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yep, it's the code I used. Actually it's 4MByte, not 16. What confuses me is why the drop to near 0 at stride=128 _combined with_ the continuous increase after that...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that but 4 MB is still RAM on the PC I used. No drop on my PC at 128 but burst reading from RAM and some caches can be 128 bytes. Need to see what instructions are used for adding to characters.